# Can you develop using .NET 3.5 SP1 and run under just .NET 3.5

Tags: entity-framework, version, .net-3.5, entities

Can I develop a website which utilizes ADO .NET Entities in the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 and then deploy it on another machine with just the .NET 3.5 framework?

Answer (score 8):

No. Your code will be referencing the Entity Framework code, and calling into it. That will fail when you try to run it on a machine which doesn't have the Entity Framework.

I also wouldn't suggest just including "extra" DLLs - getting in a state where you're using some code from 3.5 and some from 3.5SP1 sounds like a recipe for disaster to me.

Comment: I'd be interested in a reason for a downvote myself, since Jon's answer is correct. The moment the app was deployed to a machine without the requisite DLLs, it would fail to run properly.

Comment: Including the extra .dll's is a bad idea for other reasons as well. The code in the base 3.5 might be updated in SP1, so even if the method signitures match that the "extra dll's" would use, there may be a number of bugs.

Install the SP on your target machine, or do without the  Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Properties of your project and then target framework maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you include the dll's that SP1 puts in the GAC (like system.web.dynamicdata for example) during setup. Normally these wouldn't be copied into your bin cause they are in the GAC.

Best thing would be to upgrade the machine to SP1, but I guess that is not an option..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this.  Right click on your references and go to properties.  Set "Copy Local" to "True".  You will essentially be deploying .NET SP1 assemblies in your local bin instead of using what is stored in the GAC.

Comment: How about mscorlib? As far as I'm aware that *can't* be run from a local version. If anything in the other SP1 assemblies relies on a bug fix in SP1 mscorlib, you're in trouble.